# Parsing single line comments

Tags: antlr4

I am trying to write a grammar for parsing single line comments. Comments starts with '--' can appear anywhere in the file.

My basic grammar looks like below.

#### Grammar (aa.g4):

```
grammar aa;

statement
    :   commentStatement* ifStatement
    |   commentStatement* returnStatement
    ;
ifStatement
    :   'if' '(' expression ')'
        returnStatement+
    ;

returnStatement  :   'return' expression ';' ;
commentStatement :   '--' (.+?) '\\n'? ;
expression       :   IDENTIFIER ;

IDENTIFIER       :   [a-z]([A-Za-z0-9\-\_])* ;
NEWLINE          :   '\r'? '\n'    -> skip ;
WS               :   [ \t\r\f\n]+ -> skip ;
```

#### Test class:

```
public class aaTest {
    static class aaListener extends aaBaseListener {
        public void enterCommentStatement(CommentStatementContext ctx) {
            System.out.println(ctx.getText());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("aa.txt");
        CharStream stream = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
        aaLexer lexer = new aaLexer(stream);
        TokenStream tokenStream = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
        aaParser parser = new aaParser(tokenStream);
        ParseTree aParseTree = parser.statement();
        ParseTreeWalker aWalker = new ParseTreeWalker();
        aWalker.walk(new aaListener(), aParseTree);;
    }
}
```

#### Input:

```
--comment1
-- if comment
if (x) --mid if comment
  --end comment
return result;
```

#### Output:

```
--comment1a
--ifcommentif(x)     <<< error output
--midifcomment
--endcomment
```

#### Queries:

1. What is the issue in parsing error output above. I need only "-- if
   comment" to be printed.
2. How do I get and output actual comment with spaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, you should define your line comment rule as you truly mean it. The non-greedy operator is not performing the way you intend.

```
LineComment
  : '--' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;
```

Second, if you want the token stream to contain information about whitespace and newline characters, you should move them to the hidden channel instead of using the `skip` command. The `skip` command completely drops the token, making it appear as though the text was never even in the input at all.

```
NEWLINE
  : '\r'? '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;

WS
  : [ \t\f]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
  ;
```

Comments will not appear in the parse tree, and you won't use `LineComment` in any of your parser rules. To get information about these tokens before or after another token in the parse tree, you can examine the tokens around a specific index directly (using [`TokenStream.get(int)`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/TokenStream.html#get(int))) or with a utility method like [`BufferedTokenStream.getHiddenTokensToRight`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BufferedTokenStream.html#getHiddenTokensToRight(int)) or [`BufferedTokenStream.getHiddenTokensToLeft`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/BufferedTokenStream.html#getHiddenTokensToLeft(int)).

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Even found a sample program in Antlr4 Definite Guide under "Broadcasting Tokens on Different Channels".